# How can I get a US visa after two refusals?

Tags: visas, usa, cameroonian-citizens

I have been refused US visas twice: the first was for a B1, followed by F1 refusal 3 weeks ago.

I am 31 and a Cameroonian. I have had a Bachelor of Science in Nursing since 2012.  I wanted to re-study nursing in the US, enrolling for an associate degree in nursing. The US Embassy Yaounde is tricky.

What should I do to overcome this situation? Can a US immigration lawyer handle it online?

Comment: It would be easier to answer if we knew why your visa applications have been refused. And why you tried getting different visas. But with the information given, my guess would be that they think your plan is to stay in US, in that case you need to demonstrate much stronger ties to your home country, I don't think a lawyer can do much there.

Comment: All due respect the problem is precisely that they are *not* tricky.  I can't speak for Cameroon.  But there is a problem where certain other African countries are so rife with corruption that even the most honest citizens are forced to systematically lie, just to get by, and it's just widely understood/forgiven.  Then they walk into a non-corrupt institution like a foreign immigration desk, with zero tolerance for lies!  Their goose is cooked because they can't change *the way they think* fast enough.

Comment: Did you apply for, and were you accepted by the accredited US institution before applying for F1? If yes, did you settle the way you'd pay for your education, and did you bring the evidence of such to the interview?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how nursing qualifications work, but if you already have a BS in Nursing, why would you want to come to the USA to study for an associates degree (which afaik is a lesser qualification)? If this is a valid question (and not just my misunderstanding), did you explain it to the visa official during your interview?

Comment: Mr Brhms I believe you are more right.I told the officer that I would like to become an international nurse.More explantion?

Answer (score 4):

[Here's an official procedure you need to follow in a nushell](https://www.usa.gov/study-in-us).

You cannot study on B1, so the first refusal was straightforward.

For F1 as you didn't mention a specific college/school/university you were going to, I assume you just wanted to go to US and then look around the colleges to study in. This is not how F1 visa works, you need to be admitted first before you apply.

Comment: You are right .Forgive my saying tricky.Please you ought to know it is not easy and I do not intent to live in US.This is the name of the school I applied for Harrisburg Area Community College in Pennsylvania.I think the case is due for an attorney.

Comment: It is not enough just to apply - you need to be **admitted** into the college, because the college must process some visa paperwork on your behalf.